# Decreasing Tensorflow Saved Model Size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deployment

I made an LSTM model on Tensorflow and saved it using the simple `model.save()` method

Structure of Generated SavedModel :

```
lstm/
├─ assets/
├─ variables/
│  ├─ variables.data-00000-of-00001 (131 mb)
│  ├─ variables.index (5 kb)
├─ keras_metadata.pb (31 kb)
├─ saved_model.pb (2 mb)
```

However, the file `variables.data-00000-of-00001` is too big for deployment through Heroku. The generate slug size comes around 650 mb.

How can I decrease the size of the model ?

Comment: probably worth a check https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/model_optimization

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I don't think this serves my purpose :(

Comment: Yes, it does, quantization and model pruning is literally what you are looking for, and they are on that page

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got what th3e article means but I have no idea how to actually implement it

Comment: the menu on the left has many links to pages with code examples

Comment: @AditMagotra! Albert's link point towards converting  the TF model to TFlite model which has very less size ( can come to KBs with proper quantization ,optimization and pruning) compared to orginial TF model and also be deployed in microcontrollers and android/ios device where memory and latency matters a lot. Attached [Lite guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models) and [TFliteconverter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter) for your reference.